# Metodo .html() cambia el largo de mi celda

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

mi problema es el siguiente
tengo una opción dentro de una tabla para deshabilitar y habilitar un grupo pero esto solo lo manejo con un texto que cambia al hacer click, esto lo controlo desde javascript con la siguiente función:

```
    var param1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('th:eq(0)');
    var texto1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('th:eq(0)').text().toString();

    var texto2 = texto1.trim(texto1);

    if(texto2 === "Deshabilitado"){ 
        var div_hab = "<i id='estatus'  aria-hidden='true'> Habilitado</i>";
        param1.html(div_hab);
        param1.attr('class', 'fa fa-unlock');

    }
```

Y viceversa....
El caso es que al hacer click en la opcion de deshabilitar/habilitar el formato de la celda se deshace quedando de esto:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dm78H.png

a esto:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4yQa.png

tengo ya delimitado el largo de cada columna de este modo:

```
                <th width="15%">Clave Grupo</th>
                <th width="35%">Materia</th>
                <th width="10%">Alumnos Inscritos</th>
                <th width="20%">Estatus</th>
                <th width="20%">Ver lista</th>
```

y la celda de la opcion es de este modo:

```
<th><i id="estatus" class="fa fa-unlock-alt text-center" aria-hidden="true"> Habilitado</i></th>
```

No se si alguien podría ayudarme a resolver este problema
Saludos.

Comment: para la longitud de la celda es preferible usar min-width

Comment: Deberías de poner un ejemplo reproducible. A mí tu ejemplo me funciona bien: https://jsfiddle.net/x2hjh9or/

Answer (score 1):

> El error es que a los `th` (`param1`) le estas asignando clases de `FontAwesome` (`param1.attr('class', 'fa fa-unlock');`) y es por esto que se *"rompe"* el formato de celda.

Soluciones:

1. Sacar: `param1.attr('class', 'fa fa-unlock');`.
2. Reemplazarlo: `param1.first().attr('class', 'fa fa-unlock')`;
3. O, paso `1` y modificar: `var div_hab = "<i id='estatus' aria-hidden='true' class="fa fa-unlock"> Habilitado</i>";`